# C++ assigning structs/objects by reference in order to avoid long lines and improve readability

Tags: c++, object, struct, copy, pass-by-reference

### Problem

Basically I am just looking for a text replacement for a object which i have to access through a nested structure so I don't have this long lines.

```
Camera cam = clients_manager.network_controlled_simulations[simulation_index].simulation.agents[agent_index].cameras[camera_index];
cam.do_stuff();
```

However this creates a copy of the Camera object. Which in turn crashes my program further down the line. Which is not the behaviour I want. I don't want a copy i just want to avoid this long lines and have readable code.

### Things i've tried

#### 1.

One way which would work:

```
Camera *cam = &clients_manager.network_controlled_simulations[simulation_index].simulation.agents[agent_index].cameras[camera_index];
(*cam).do_stuff();
```

But then everytime i want to use a method or property I have to do (*cam).property and (*cam).method()

I'd prefer accessing it like:

```
cam.property
```

#### 2.

So i thought I would do:

```
Camera cam;
*cam = &clients_manager.network_controlled_simulations[simulation_index].simulation.agents[agent_index].cameras[camera_index];
```

Which gives me the error:

```
No operator "*" matches these operands
Operand types are: * Camera
```

#### 3.

Then Well let's try address operator & :

```
Camera cam;
&cam = &clients_manager.network_controlled_simulations[simulation_index].simulation.agents[agent_index].cameras[camera_index];
```

which gives me another error:

```
expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

### Question

Is there any way to achieve what I want or should I just settle with the solution i found ?

Comment: References are essential to write any non-trivial code, you should read about them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Since your object's subscript operator already returns cameras by reference, what about using a reference instead ? `Camera & cam = ...;`

Comment: "But then everytime i want to use a method or property I have to do (*cam).property and (*cam).method()" No. `cam->property` or `cam->method()` is the canonical way to dereference and access a member

Comment: Use a reference `Camera& cam = clients_manager.network_controlled_simulations[simulation_index].simulation.agents[agent_index].cameras[camera_index];`

Comment: Thank you @StackDanny Fareanor and 463035818-is-not-a-number . Question can be closed .

Comment: @john thank you as well, that's the solution yes. I didn't knew about reference variable. I always thought they were just operators used in function signatures to indicate pass by reference or to access the adress of an existing object. Thx everyone I am gonna stop replying now.